# How to apply conditions on pandas dataframe columns?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I have a pandas dataframe that has information on rejections. A little background on the problem, an email sender may send the same email multiple times, but it is only resolved once. I want to still account for the emails that have the same sender and same message as 'resolved' in a new column.

The starting dataframe looks like this:

```
data = [['Sent from automated email', 'jim@yahoo.com', 'Resolved','2020-01-13 07:06:34'], 
        ['Sent from automated email', 'jim@yahoo.com', 'Rejected','2020-01-13 07:06:39'], 
        ['Hello I would like for you to make an update please','new101@cnn.com', 'Resolved', '2020-02-14 09:06:39'], 
        ['Hello I would like for you to make an update please','new101@cnn.com', 'Rejected', '2020-02-14 09:06:41'],
        ['Hello I would like for you to make an update please','new101@cnn.com', 'Resolved', '2020-02-14 09:06:59'],
        ['Take one newspaper','notneeded@gmail.com', 'Resolved', '2020-02-17 09:05:39'],
        ['Hey hows it going','jamie@gmail.com', 'Rejected', '2020-03-12 09:03:42'],
        ] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Message', 'Email','Resolution','Time Sent'])
```

I want to take all the emails that have the same sender and the same message, but different resolutions and label them as 'resolved' if any of prior emails were resolved. My desired output is would be:

```
data = [['Sent from automated email', 'jim@yahoo.com', 'Resolved','2020-01-13 07:06:34','Resolved' ], 
        ['Sent from automated email', 'jim@yahoo.com', 'Rejected','2020-01-13 07:06:39','Resolved'], 
        ['Hello I would like for you to make an update please','new101@cnn.com', 'Resolved', '2020-02-14 09:06:39','Resolved'], 
        ['Hello I would like for you to make an update please','new101@cnn.com', 'Rejected', '2020-02-14 09:06:41','Resolved'],
        ['Hello I would like for you to make an update please','new101@cnn.com', 'Resolved', '2020-02-14 09:06:59','Resolved'],
        ] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Message', 'Email','Resolution','Time Sent','Real Resolution'])
```

I have tried writing a function like below:

```
    def a(df):
        if df[df['message'].duplicated()] & df[(df['resolution'] == 'Rejected') | (df['resolution'] == 'Resolved') ] & df[df['Email].duplicated()]:
           df['Real Resolution'] = 'Resolved' 

df['Real Resolution'] = df.apply(a)
```

I do not think this is correct since I am not accounting for only duplicated messages that are Resolved and then rejected. Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: what happens to the last 2 rows?  they are deleted from output?

Comment: yes, they are not carried over since the message and sender combo do not appear in the dataframe elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try the below:

```
c = df[['Message','Email']].duplicated(keep=False) #check duplicate in Message+Email
c1 = df[['Message','Email','Resolution']].duplicated(keep=False) #check resolution too
#condition is if c is True and c1 is False then check if email group has any True
df.loc[(c & ~c1).groupby(df['Email']).transform('any'),'Real Resolution'] = 'Resolved'

out = df.dropna(subset=['Real Resolution']).copy()
print(out)
```

---

```
                                             Message           Email  \
0                          Sent from automated email   jim@yahoo.com   
1                          Sent from automated email   jim@yahoo.com   
2  Hello I would like for you to make an update p...  new101@cnn.com   
3  Hello I would like for you to make an update p...  new101@cnn.com   
4  Hello I would like for you to make an update p...  new101@cnn.com   

  Resolution            Time Sent Real Resolution  
0   Resolved  2020-01-13 07:06:34        Resolved  
1   Rejected  2020-01-13 07:06:39        Resolved  
2   Resolved  2020-02-14 09:06:39        Resolved  
3   Rejected  2020-02-14 09:06:41        Resolved  
4   Resolved  2020-02-14 09:06:59        Resolved
```